# PregMatch php code to Objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c

I have the following PHP code:

```
public static function getCardTypeFromNumber($number) {
    $ccTypes = array(
        '3[47]'      => self::Type_Amex,
        '6(?:5|011)' => self::Type_Disc,
        '5[1-5]'     => self::Type_MC,
        '4'          => self::Type_Visa,
    );

    foreach ($ccTypes as $prefix => $type) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . $prefix . '/', $number)) { return $type; }
    }
```

I am trying to convert it into Objective-c, but I don't know where to start?

Can anyone please help?

I know how to do everything but the preg_match part ... What is the objective-c equivalent of the preg_match code above?

Here's what I have so far?

```
NSDictionary * cardTypes = @{@"3[47]": WPCardTypeAmex,
                 @"6(?:5|011)": WPCarddTypeDiscover,
                 @"5[1-5]": WPCardTypeMasterCard,
                             @"4": WPCardTypeVisa};

for (NSString * key in cardTypes) {
    NSString * value = [cardTypes objectForKey:key];

    [self.number rangeOfString: value options: NSRegularExpressionSearch];

}
```

Does that work?

Comment: Of course `represent the array --- by using NSDictionary` is wrong because `NSDictionary` is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `preg_match` use

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
```

With the option `NSRegularExpressionSearch`.

Check range.location not equal to `NSNotFound`